# Gerrit submit change to a git submodule

Tags: git-submodules, gerrit

I have a gerrit repo with a submodule:

```
parent
  submodule
```

Now I make some change to submodule and want to push that to gerrit. Unfortunately the submodule is set up only as a git repo, not a gerrit repo, because gerrit repo has remote url that contains my username, thus cannot be checked into the .`gitmodules` file. So is there a convenient way to set up the submodule also as a gerrit repo when I clone `parent`?

So far my colleagues have all told me to patch whatever change in the submodule to a separate gerrit cloned copy of the submodule. But this seems rather inefficient. I see no reason why gerrit remote urls should not be propagated to all the submodules, recursively. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but you don't need to add your username in the repository remote url in the .gitmodules file. Just use something like that:

```
url=https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/REPO-PATH
```

When the username is not mentioned the default USER will be used.

Comment: Thanks. The default user has permission issue. Gerrit server is set up with rsa keys.